# Add multicols column in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

Is it possible to add the column of an section/subsection in an multicol environment to the table of contents?

The table of content looks like this in the moment

```
1. Headline 1 ......... 1 % Shows only the page
2. Headline 2 ......... 1
3. Headline 3 ......... 1
```

But I want it to look like this

```
1. Headline 1 ......... 1.1 % <page>.<column>
2. Headline 2 ......... 1.3
3. Headline 3 ......... 1.5
```

Here is a minimal example, which has to be extended:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{5}

\tableofcontents
\section{Headline 1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Headline 2}
\lipsum[4-6]

\section{Headline 3}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! it is not clear what you like to obtain. your mwe works (as expected), however, section out of `multicols*` start new page ... what is your real problem?

Comment: If you want to put the sections in one column and the subsections in another (overlappping) you coulod do it with paracol, but you will need to customize \l@section and \l@subsection to use \leftcolumn and \rightcolumn.

Comment: The table of contents shows only the pages, but I want to add the corresponding columns in which the section is defined to find them faster.

Comment: Are your readers really so helpless that they can't make the "leap" from the table of contents to a sectioning header on some unless both the page number and the column number are printed in the ToC?

Comment: I have really many subsections on each page since it's a cheatsheet for a lecture. So knowing the corresponding column would really help.

Comment: You have a toc for a cheat sheet? Why? Usually they are 2 sides of 1 sheet - and there's no room for a toc, even if such a thing would be useful. Maybe you mean something else, though.

Comment: Usually, yes. But in this case we are allowed to bring more sheets. So just the general question if it is possible to determine the current column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you want. It needs a few runs (3) to display everything
correct. The option `colaction` is necessary for the command `\docolaction` and for the patch to work.

**New answer for arbitrary number of columns**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{brnk@col@count}
\renewcommand*\addcontentsline[3]
  {%
    \addtocontents{#1}
      {%
        \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}
          {\thepage\ifnum\doublecol@number>0\relax.\string\brnk@cur@col\fi}%
      }%
  }
\def\brnk@patch@last
  {%
    \stepcounter{brnk@col@count}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
      {%
        \string\@writefile{toc}%
          {\string\def\string\brnk@cur@col{\arabic{brnk@col@count}}}%
      }%
  }
\def\brnk@patch@else
  {%
    \ifmc@firstcol
      \setcounter{brnk@col@count}{0}%
    \fi
    \brnk@patch@last
  }
\def\brnk@patch@error
  {%
    \GenericError{}
      {Patching of \string\mc@col@status@write\space failed}
      {%
        Make sure `colaction` was set as an option for `multicol`.%
        \MessageBreak
        Else you're screwed, don't use the code provided here.\MessageBreak%
      }
      {No further help available.}%
  }
\pretocmd\mc@lastcol@status@write{\brnk@patch@last}{}{\brnk@patch@error}
\pretocmd\mc@col@status@write{\brnk@patch@else}{}{\brnk@patch@error}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{5}

\tableofcontents
\section{Headline 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Headline 2}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Headline 3}
\lipsum[4-7]

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[8]
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\lipsum[9]
\end{multicols*}
\section{Headline 4}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Headline 5}
\lipsum[6]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Original answer for only 3 columns**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\addcontentsline[3]{%
  \def\brnk@column{}%
  \ifnum\doublecol@number>0
    \docolaction
      [5]
      {\def\brnk@column{.1}}
      {\def\brnk@column{.2}}
      {\def\brnk@column{.3}}%
  \fi
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}
    {\thepage\brnk@column}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tableofcontents
\section{Headline 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Headline 2}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Headline 3}
\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols*}
\section{Headline 4}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Headline 5}
\lipsum[6]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: I looked up the docolaction command in the documentation and it states that it's only for three columns (left, middle, right). But I have 5 columns. I just used three columns in the minimal example to make the document easier to read.

Comment: Another problem is that my subsections are defined inside the multicols in a different environment. Is it possible to check whether the multicols environment is a parent instead of checking whether it is the current environment?

Comment: @brnk the edit uses a better test. For the support of more than 3 columns I can't do anything right now, but will get back at it later this day (hopefully).

Comment: @brnk sorry to disappoint you. A solution for 5 columns seems possible, but I'm neither willing nor have the time to create and test it. You could send a feature request to the maintainers of `multicol` and hope for the best, though.

Comment: @brnk sorry to disappoint you again, but I did create some code which works for 5 columns (in fact it should work for an arbitrary number of columns). I didn't test it too much, so it might not be perfectly stable.