# Know in which column am I in

Tags: multicol, programming

it there a way to have a variable that returns in which column of my multicols environment am I in?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a bit of context for what you need to know the column number?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414638/117050 there I wrote some code to get the current column inside of a ToC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting current column in multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108793/detecting-current-column-in-multicol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box `multicol` supports finding out if you are at a certain point in the first, the last or one of the middle columns (assuming you have more than 2 columns). That is done using `\docolaction` which is described in the documentation (and needs to be explicitly enabled via an option). If you need more detail then perhaps the link suggested above provides that, but by default `multicol` distinguishes ones the 3 cases.

Answer (score 5):

The following yields the current column unexpandably. It needs at least 2 runs of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[left=2mm,right=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{nexprex@col@count}
\newcounter{nexprex@current@column@call}
\def\nexprex@patch@last
  {%
    \stepcounter{nexprex@col@count}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}
      {%
        \string\def\string\nexprex@cur@col{\arabic{nexprex@col@count}}%
      }%
  }
\def\nexprex@patch@else
  {%
    \ifmc@firstcol
      \setcounter{nexprex@col@count}{0}%
    \fi
    \nexprex@patch@last
  }
\def\nexprex@patch@error
  {%
    \GenericError{}
      {Patching of \string\mc@col@status@write\space failed}
      {%
        Make sure `colaction` was set as an option for `multicol`.%
        \MessageBreak
        Else you're screwed, don't use the code provided here.\MessageBreak%
      }
      {No further help available.}%
  }
\pretocmd\mc@lastcol@status@write{\nexprex@patch@last}{}{\nexprex@patch@error}
\pretocmd\mc@col@status@write{\nexprex@patch@else}{}{\nexprex@patch@error}
\newcommand\currentcolumn
  {%
    \stepcounter{nexprex@current@column@call}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}
      {%
        \string\expandafter
        \string\global
        \string\expandafter
        \string\let
          \string\csname\space
            nexprex@current@column@\arabic{nexprex@current@column@call}%
          \string\endcsname
          \string\nexprex@cur@col
      }%
    \ifcsname
      nexprex@current@column@\arabic{nexprex@current@column@call}\endcsname
      \csname
        nexprex@current@column@\arabic{nexprex@current@column@call}\endcsname
    \fi
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
  \noindent
  This is: \currentcolumn
  \columnbreak\\
  This is: \currentcolumn
  \columnbreak\\
  This is: \currentcolumn
  \columnbreak\\
  This is: \currentcolumn
  \columnbreak\\
  This is: \currentcolumn
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done! Why we need at least 2 runs of LaTeX? Why should this happen?

Comment: @manooooh because the code I inject into `\mc@lastcol@status@write` and `\mc@col@status@write` is executed at ship out time and the counter isn't yet increased. Therefore we move the definitions of the current columns into the aux file.