# How to know which column a text is in

Tags: margins, conditionals, two-column

I want to put a small circle with a letter at the margin in a two-column document. To decide in which margin this bullet goes, I use `\if@firstcolumn`.

It works most of the time, but it sometimes goes wrong in the first paragraph of a new colum. It seems `\if@firstcolumn` delays a little to be updated.

I currently use the option `twocolumn` with `article`. I don't intend to switch to package `multicol`, to which a solution seems to be available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471290/know-in-which-column-am-i-in).

How can I truly know the current column?

My MWE. I don't want the red arrow; it's there only for visualization. This code actually puts a list of bullets. This MWE produces the issue from the second page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper height = 10cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, tikzmark}
\newcounter{nivel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\niveis}[1]{%
    \if@twocolumn%
        \if@firstcolumn%
            \def\ancora{east}%
            \def\margem{west}%
            \def\deslocamento{+2.25cm}%
        \else%
            \def\ancora{west}%
            \def\margem{east}%
            \def\deslocamento{-2.25cm}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \stepcounter{nivel}%
    \tikzmark{exercicio-\thenivel}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
        every node/.style = {
            align = center,
            font=\footnotesize\bfseries\sffamily\color{white},
            anchor = center,
        },
        ]
        \coordinate (base) at
            ($(current page.\margem|-{pic cs:exercicio-\thenivel})
            + (\oddsidemargin+\hoffset\deslocamento, 0)$);
        \foreach \n[count = \k from 0] in {#1}{
            \coordinate (item) at ($(base) - (0, 0.6cm * \k)$);
            \draw[thick, red, <-] ({pic cs:exercicio-\thenivel}) -- (item);
            \path[fill = black!75] (item) circle (0.25cm);
            \node at (item) {\n};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\whichcolumn}{\if@firstcolumn LEFT\else RIGHT\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1, ..., 50}{
    \whichcolumn (\i)\niveis{A, B} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Um enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco is in the \whichcolumn\ column.\par%
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code adaptation uses [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module to store the x-coordinate on the left side of the text you're placing (`LEFT` or `RIGHT`). This x-coordinate is used to identify whether you're in the left/right column, depending on whether it's less than or greater than (or equal to) 50% of the page width. Since you're using [`tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgf) already, you can use [`tikzmark`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) as well. I'm just not as familiar with it as much as `zref-savepos`.

With the first compilation, all elements are considered `LEFT`, since the x-coordinate has not been stored and recalled successfully. Over the next couple of compilation, this changes, with elements shifting to the `RIGHT` as needed. This increases the text in some paragraphs, leading to differing overflow between left/right columns, and consequently differing placements of the `tikz` arrows and text boxes. In short, you'll have to compile a couple of times until these references "settle." Once that's the case, there only changes in the marking locations may cause additional compilations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[paper height = 10cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{columncheck}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, tikzmark}
\newcounter{nivel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\niveis}[1]{%
  \if@twocolumn%
    \leftorright{%
      \def\ancora{east}%
      \def\margem{west}%
      \def\deslocamento{+2.25cm}%
    }{%
      \def\ancora{west}%
      \def\margem{east}%
      \def\deslocamento{-2.25cm}%
    }%
  \fi%
  \stepcounter{nivel}%
  \tikzmark{exercicio-\thenivel}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
    every node/.style = {
      align = center,
      font=\footnotesize\bfseries\sffamily\color{white},
      anchor = center,
    },
    ]
    \coordinate (base) at
      ($(current page.\margem|-{pic cs:exercicio-\thenivel})
      + (\oddsidemargin+\hoffset\deslocamento, 0)$);
    \foreach \n[count = \k from 0] in {#1}{
      \coordinate (item) at ($(base) - (0, 0.6cm * \k)$);
      \draw[thick, red, <-] ({pic cs:exercicio-\thenivel}) -- (item);
      \path[fill = black!75] (item) circle (0.25cm);
      \node at (item) {\n};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\whichcolumn}{%
  \stepcounter{columncheck}%
  \zsaveposx{columncheck-\thecolumncheck}%
  \ifdim.5\paperwidth > \zposx{columncheck-\thecolumncheck}sp
    LEFT%
    \let\leftorright\@firstoftwo
  \else
    RIGHT%
    \let\leftorright\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1, ..., 50}{
  \mbox{}\whichcolumn (\i)\niveis{A, B} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Um enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco is in the \whichcolumn\ column.\par%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. I tried your approach (compare to the page center) unsuccessfully using `tikzmark`. Totally forgot about `zref-savepos`. And learned also `@firstoftwo`...