# Know which column I am in in a float

Tags: floats, two-column

Can code a float know which column if a `twocolumn` document it is set in? I am fine with solutions that only works correctly after a number of recompiles. The code that I want to make dependent on this will not change the size of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example uses [Werner`s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543802/161015) for a similar problem to identify the column.

**UPDATE** after follow-up question: asymmetric margins.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=4.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, marginpar=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{zref-savepos} % needed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{columncheck}    
\newlength{\ldistance}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text <<
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543802/161015
\newcommand{\whichcolumn}{%
    \hspace*{0.25\textwidth}% center in the column
    \setlength{\ldistance}{0.5\paperwidth}
    \stepcounter{columncheck}%
    \zsaveposx{\thecolumncheck}% \zsaveposx{<label>}
    \ifdim\ldistance > \zposx{\thecolumncheck}sp % get stored x pos in sp units
    LEFT\else RIGHT\fi
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
    
    1.  \kant[1]
    
    \begin{figure}[htp!]    
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}\\
    \whichcolumn
    \end{figure}
    
    2. \kant[3]
    
    \begin{figure}[tp!]         
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}\\
        \whichcolumn
    \end{figure}
            
    3.  \kant[1-3]
    
    \begin{figure}[htp!]        
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}\\\medskip
        \whichcolumn
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[htp!]
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}\\
        \whichcolumn
    \end{figure}

    \newpage
    \begin{figure}[ht!] 
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c.jpg}\\
    \whichcolumn
\end{figure}

4.  \kant[1-2]
        
\end{document}
```

> This code uses `zref's savepos` module to store the x-coordinate of
> the center of the column you're placing the command. This
> x-coordinate is used to identify whether you're in the left/right
> column, depending on whether it's less than or greater than (or equal> to) 50% of the page area.

Comment: Are you sure that works? I can't compile that (pdflatex or xelatex from texlive 2022). See https://pastebin.com/QcEpc1M7 for my log file. EDIT: probably should be `\paperwidth`, not `\pagewidth`?

Comment: With that change it works, but often produces wrong results.

Comment: Okay, the second is not your fault, but due to my asymmetric margins. Sorry for that. But maybe interesting for others.

Comment: @Bubaya Thank you for your feedback!. You are right, it requires `\paperwidth` using pdflatex. The code was slightly modified to accommodate asymmetrical margins (up to a point!) by using the center of the column instead of its left side as a reference.

Comment: Great, thank you! Made my code much simpler.